# How Can I fix it?Error [NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper copy]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created (`NSCalendar* cal;`) when I copy   it to use (`NSCalendar* calendar = [cal copy];`) this is error 
**Error [NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper copy]: message sent to deallocated instance**
How Can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, but you have provided not enough info on your issue. Where have you created `cal`, what happens before your initializion?

Comment: Hi  I have created (NSCalendar*cal) when I use (NSCalendar* calendar = [cal copy];) but I it error(@interface IQGanttHeaderView : UIView <IQGanttHeaderDelegate> {
@private
    char weekdayLetters[8];
    NSCalendar* cal;
    NSDateFormatter* monthNameFormatter;
}     I use it in methob                                                                                      (void)moveLabels
{
    NSTimeInterval t0 = scaleWindow.viewStart;
    NSTimeInterval t1 = scaleWindow.viewStart + scaleWindow.viewSize;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [cal copy];

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going wrong but `enabling zombie objects` will help you to get to the object which is deallocated:

[image: edit your scheme]
[image: enable zombie objects]

**Do not forget to disable it, as no objects will get deallocated while this is enabled.**

Answer (score 0):

I bet cal is not initialized yet when you call [cal copy]. Try change

```
NSCalendar *cal;
```

to:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

and see whether you still get the same error message.

On the other hand, you should seldom need to copy NSCalendar object.